# Calling scrollToPosition() after executing a method

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

```
 messageList.scrollToPosition(messages.size()- 1);
```

Just trying a basic chat app and I want to scroll to the bottom of the recyclerview once a new message is sent so I added this line after sending a message and it doesn't work...

messageList is the reyclerview and
messages is the arraylist

I also tried

```
 messageList.scrollToPosition(- 1);
```

No luck. Can someone help me out

Comment: Can you confirm that `messages.size()` returns proper result ?

Comment: Please send more code snippet.

Comment: Yes it does @CoderCroc

Comment: What more do you need @ChiragSolankI